# change the language of an AWS RDS instance to French

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created an RDS instance on AWS and the default language is English. I want the language of the instance to be French, so I created a new parameter group and attached it to my RDS database.

I changed the language to French in this parameter group, but it only applies to new users.

So, I created a new user, and now I want to give this user some roles, including dbcreator, public, and Bulkadmin.

create new user :
`CREATE LOGIN mylogin WITH PASSWORD = 'mypassword';`

How can I add the desired roles to my new user?

Thanks for your help